# Path element include on condition

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

All,

Can someone please help on how to include a directory in a path element conditionally if the directory exists: So like below

```
<path id="lib.path.ref">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <path location="${build.dir}" if="${build.dir.exist}"  />
</path>
```

This currently does not work because path element does not support the if attribute. In my case, I want to include build.dir if only it exists.

Thanks

Comment: just found this one for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666718/need-to-set-path-cp-in-ant-script-depending-on-value-of-a-property may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without installing [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) or similar Ant extensions, you can accomplish what you want with the following XML:

```
<project default="echo-lib-path">
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <available file="${build.dir}" type="dir" property="build.dir.exists"/>

    <target name="-set-path-with-build-dir" if="build.dir.exists">
        <echo message="Executed -set-path-with-build-dir"/>
        <path id="lib.path.ref">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <path location="${build.dir}" />
        </path>
    </target>

    <target name="-set-path-without-build-dir" unless="build.dir.exists">
        <echo message="Executed -set-path-without-build-dir"/>
        <path id="lib.path.ref">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
    </target>

    <target name="-init" depends="-set-path-with-build-dir, -set-path-without-build-dir"/>

    <target name="echo-lib-path" depends="-init">
        <property name="lib.path.property" refid="lib.path.ref"/>
        <echo message="${lib.path.property}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The important part here is what happens in the `-init` target. It depends upon the `-set-path-with-build-dir` and `-set-path-without-build-dir` targets, but Ant only executes one target based upon whether `build.dir.exists` is set or not.

Read more about the Available Task here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out time to give a clear and concise working solution. Appreciate this community.